# Face recognition through microsoft azure face api

Tags: python, face-recognition, face-api

I took a python program from a github repo where it uses azure face api to recognize faces. When I run the code the following errors occur.
I am not sure whether it a fault in the "face_api_url"..

```
Define the group name -> family
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python-azure-ai-face-recognition\face_recognition.py", line 126, in <module>
    start()
  File "D:\python-azure-ai-face-recognition\face_recognition.py", line 60, in start
    list(map(lambda x: create_group(x), GROUPS))
  File "D:\python-azure-ai-face-recognition\face_recognition.py", line 60, in <lambda>
    list(map(lambda x: create_group(x), GROUPS))
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\python-azure-ai-face-recognition\face_recognition.py", line 29, in create_group
    face_client.person_group.create(person_group_id=group, name=group)
  File "C:\Users\Rushika\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\azure\cognitiveservices\vision\face\operations\_person_group_operations.py", line 121, in create
    raise models.APIErrorException(self._deserialize, response)
azure.cognitiveservices.vision.face.models._models_py3.APIErrorException: (InvalidRequest) Invalid request has been sent.
```

The code I took is the below one. I imported all the necessary libraries and everything. The endpoint and the key are provided in a JSON file. Only thing I am not sure is the 'face_api_url'. I could not found a proper definition for it in the web

```
import cv2
import requests
import time
import json
import glob
import sys
from azure.cognitiveservices.vision.face import FaceClient
from msrest.authentication import CognitiveServicesCredentials

# Variables
#path = 'D:\python-azure-ai-face-recognition\json_key.json'

credentials = json.load(open('./json_key.json'))
KEY = credentials['KEY']
ENDPOINT = credentials['ENDPOINT']

face_api_url = "https://eastusrushikafr.cognitiveservices.azure.com/face/v1.0/detect"
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream', 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': KEY}
params = {'detectionModel': 'detection_01', 'returnFaceId': 'true', 'returnFaceRectangle': 'true', 'returnFaceAttributes': 'age, gender, emotion'}

GROUPS = []
PEOPLE = []
ID = []

face_client = FaceClient(ENDPOINT, CognitiveServicesCredentials(KEY))

# Functions
def create_group(group):
    face_client.person_group.create(person_group_id=group, name=group)
    print('Created group {}'.format(group))

def create_person(person, group):
    globals()[person] = face_client.person_group_person.create(group, person)
    print('Person ID:', globals()[person].person_id)
    ID.append(globals()[person].person_id)

    photo_list = [file for file in glob.glob('*.jpg') if file.startswith(person)]
    time.sleep(1)
    for image in photo_list:
        face_client.person_group_person.add_face_from_stream(
            GROUPS[0], globals()[person].person_id, open(image, 'r+b'))
        print('Included photo {}'.format(image))
        time.sleep(1)

def train(group):
    print('Starting training for {}'.format(group))
    face_client.person_group.train(group)
    while (True):
        training_status = face_client.person_group.get_training_status(group)
        print("Training status of {}: {}.".format(group, training_status.status))
        if (training_status.status == 'succeeded'):
            break
        elif (training_status.status == 'failed'):
            face_client.person_group.delete(person_group_id=group)
            sys.exit('Training the person group has failed.')
        time.sleep(5)

def start():
    GROUPS.append(input('Define the group name -> ').lower())
    list(map(lambda x: create_group(x), GROUPS))

    people_list = []
    person_name = None
    while person_name != 'end':
        person_name = input("Enter the name of the person to associate with the group '{}' or type 'end' to finish. -> ".format(GROUPS[0])).lower()
        if person_name != 'end':
            PEOPLE.append(person_name)
            people_list.append(person_name)

    if len(people_list) == 1:
        print('{} has been added to the group {}'.format(PEOPLE[0], GROUPS[0]))
    else:
        last_name = people_list.pop()
        names = ', '.join(people_list)
        print('{} and {} have been added to the group {}'.format(names, last_name, GROUPS[0]))

    list(map(lambda x: create_person(x, GROUPS[0]), PEOPLE))
    list(map(lambda x: train(x), GROUPS))

    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    while True:
        ret, frame = cam.read()
        image = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)[1].tobytes()

        response = requests.post(face_api_url, params=params, headers=headers, data=image)
        response.raise_for_status()
        faces = response.json()
        face_ids = [face['faceId'] for face in faces]

        global results
        for face in face_ids:
            results = face_client.face.identify(face_ids, GROUPS[0])

        # Obtaining landmarks
        for n, (face, person, id, name) in enumerate(zip(faces, results, ID, PEOPLE)):
            rect = face['faceRectangle']
            left, top = rect['left'], rect['top']
            right = int(rect['width'] + left)
            bottom = int(rect['height'] + top)

            draw_rect = cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 255, 0), 3)
            att = face['faceAttributes']
            age = att['age']

            if len(person.candidates) > 0 and str(person.candidates[0].person_id) == str(id):
                print('Person for face ID {} is identified in {}.{}'.format(person.face_id, 'Frame', person.candidates[0].person_id))
                draw_text = cv2.putText(frame, 'Name: {}'.format(name), (left, bottom + 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
                faces[n]['name'] = str(name)
            else:
                draw_text = cv2.putText(frame, 'Name: Unknown', (left, bottom + 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
                faces[n]['name'] = 'Unknown'

        cv2.imshow('face_rect', draw_rect)

        k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF  # bitwise AND operation to get the last 8 bits
        if k == 27:
            print("Escape hit, closing...")
            break

def end(group_name):
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    face_client.person_group.delete(person_group_id=group_name)

# Start the code
start()
# Stop and clean
end('group_name')
```

Answer (score 0):

You gets this error because many features of the Face API are locked down except for Limited Access customers.

**According to Microsoft:**
Face service access is limited based on eligibility and usage criteria in order to support our Responsible AI principles. You got this error since what you are trying to call is now limited access to them because you have not been approved to use that capability.

See also: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/responsible-ai-investments-and-safeguards-for-facial-recognition/